# Telegram API - InlineKeyboardMarkup не отображается

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу pet проект для заказа еды в кафе. По задумке после /start пользователю выдается меню в виде InlineKeyboardMarkup, затем обрабатываю нажатия на кнопки.

```
public InlineKeyboardMarkup createMenuKeyboard() {
        InlineKeyboardMarkup keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
        keyboard.addRow(new InlineKeyboardButton("Пицца").callbackData("pizza"));
        keyboard.addRow(new InlineKeyboardButton("Суши").callbackData("sushi"));
        keyboard.addRow(new InlineKeyboardButton("Бургеры").callbackData("burger"));
        keyboard.addRow(new InlineKeyboardButton("Салаты").callbackData("salad"));
        return keyboard;
    }
```

```
clientBot.execute(new SendMessage(clientId, botMessage).replyMarkup(createMenuKeyboard()));
        if (update.callbackQuery() != null) {
            String data = update.callbackQuery().data();
            clientId = update.callbackQuery().message().chat().id();
            if (data.equals("pizza")) {
               clientBot.execute(menuService.sendFoodMenu(clientId, FoodType.PIZZA));
            }
        }
```

В ответ пользователь должен получить список кнопок с названиями блюд. Проблема в том что не отрисовывают кнопки после обработки.

Делаю запрос в БД в зависимости от типа которым подписана кнопка.

```
        Class<? extends Food> foodClass = foodType.getFoodClass();
        ResolvableType resolvableType = ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(FoodRepository.class, foodClass, Long.class);
        FoodRepository<? extends Food, Long> foodRepository =
                (FoodRepository<? extends Food, Long>) applicationContext.getBeanProvider(resolvableType).getObject();
        List<? extends Food> foods = foodRepository.findAll();
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> inlineKeyboardButtons = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Food food : foods) {
            inlineKeyboardButtons.add(food.getButtons());
        }
        return inlineKeyboardButtons;
    }
```

Создаю кнопку в классе блюда.

```
@Override
    public InlineKeyboardButton getButtons() {
        return new InlineKeyboardButton(getName());
    }
```

И отправляю ответ пользователю. Если не прикреплять InlineKeyboardMarkup к ответу, то ответ в чат приходит, с ним же ничего. Ошибок в логах нет.

```
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> buttons = getButton(foodType);
        InlineKeyboardMarkup keyboard =
                new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
        for (InlineKeyboardButton button : buttons) {
            keyboard.addRow(button);
        }
       return new SendMessage(chatId, "Выберите " + foodType.name().toLowerCase() + " из меню:").replyMarkup(keyboard);
    }
```

Comment: Поищите ошибки в логах, вы не передаете обязательный аргумент при создании кнопки, должна быть ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В соответствии с документацией, у объекта [`InlineKeyboardButton`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) поле `text` обязательное. Но кроме этого, вы должны задать **ровно одно** из опциональных полей.

Сейчас в вашем коде при создании объекта `InlineKeyboardButton` передается только текст. Передайте недостающий аргумент. Это может быть или `url`, или `callback_data`, или [ряд других](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) параметров.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы были правы. ```@Override
    public InlineKeyboardButton getButtons() {
        return new InlineKeyboardButton(getName()).callbackData(" ");
    }``` сработало

Comment: Не забудьте указать более осмысленное значение в callback-data, чтобы вы могли обработать действие по кнопке. Так же, как у вас уже сделано для других кнопок.

Comment: да, разумеется, сейчас пока никакой логики просто нет. Главное, что теперь можно двигаться дальше. Два дня не мог решить эту проблему...